# Determine cumulative distribution function

Tags: probability

Consider a random variable $X$ with mass function $p_{X}(x)$ given by:

$$P(X=k) =\frac{6k^2}{n(n+1)(2n+1)}, \quad k= 1, \dots, n$$
I want determine the cumulative distribution function of $X$

We know that

$$F_{X}(k)=P(X \leq k)= P\left(\bigcup_{k' \leq k} \{X=k' \} \right)=\sum_{k' \leq k} p_{X}(k')$$

In our case this looks something like

$$F_{X}(x)=P(X \leq k)=\sum_{k'=1}^{k} P(X=k')=\frac{6k'^2}{k'(k'+1)(2k'+1)}$$

But something I don't understand is if $k$ goes from one to $n$, how does this influence the final result. How can I conclude the answer? any suggestion will be welcome!

Comment: Why have you replaced the $n$s in the mass function with $k'$ in the denominator of your cumulative distribution function?  The random variable is $k$, not $n$.

Comment: $F_{X}(k)=P(X \leq k)=\sum\limits_{k'=1}^{k} P(X=k')=\sum\limits_{k'=1}^{k}\dfrac{6k'^2}{n(n+1)(2n+1)}$ $=\dfrac{6}{n(n+1)(2n+1)}\sum\limits_{k'=1}^{k} k'^2$ at least for integer $k$ between $1$ to $n$.  The sum over $k'$ is easy

Comment: @Henry If I am honest, I have been thinking for a while about the last sum but I don't see where is the facility for the computation, any help?

Comment: What do you mean by "facility for the computation"?

Comment: As a shortcut, $\sum_{i=1}^n i^2 = n(n+1)(2n+1)/6$, as you should be able to deduce from your first equation!

Comment: @jbowman I mean to find  $\sum_{k'=1}^{k} k'^{2}$ considering that $k=1, \dots, n$

Comment: @jbowman Maybe it's the same thing you presented in your last comment?